# FFMpeg error in Xcode 9 - Definition of type 'AVMediaType' conflicts with typedef of the same name

Tags: ios, swift, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am trying to stream a live video(rtsp) using  `ffmpeg library`
in avutil.h

[image]

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you import `AVFoundation`?

Comment: imported in the project not in the file

Comment: Don't name it 'AVMediaType'?

Comment: @ElTomato: It is in the ffmpeg library. We can not modify

Answer (score 0):

It's happened in Xcode9 ,so you can change AVMediaType to FF_AVMediaType in list files: avcodec.h   avfilter.h   avformat.h   avutil.h